# Why trap does not work to interrupt nohup command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, signals, nohup

this is a script, the name is test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cleanup(){
    echo "Caught SIGINT ..."
    exit 1

}    
trap 'cleanup' 3
    while :;do
        echo "a"
        sleep 3
    done
```

if I run `nohup ./test.sh &` in linux bash directly , it can catch kill -3 PID signal ,

but if I write `nohup ./test.sh &` in a script file that name is **go.sh**) ,and I run **go.sh** , an then **test.sh**  can't catch  kill -3 PID signal

how can I write the **go.sh** script to make sure  **test.sh** catch -3 signal ?

Comment: Just a note - the signal `3` is `SIGQUIT`. The `SIGINT` is `2`.

Answer (score 1):

`kill -3` (`SIGQUIT`) would not work. According to bash's manual:

> When bash is interactive, in the absence of any traps, it ignores `SIGTERM` (so that `kill 0` does not kill an interactive shell), and `SIGINT` is caught and handled (so that the wait builtin is interruptible).  **In  all cases, bash ignores `SIGQUIT`.**  If job control is in effect, bash ignores `SIGTTIN`, `SIGTTOU`, and `SIGTSTP`.